# How to make cell Label components of a Table to occupy all of the grid cell area?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have a Table , and I set its components UIID to oddRowsCell and evenRowsCell if the row is odd or even. In the resource editor I set background color styles for both UIID in the selected and unselected options.
The problem is that in runtime the Label which renders the table cells is not fully occupying the Table's grid cells. So how to make the Label occupy the Tables's grid cell ?

Thank you very much indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the padding of the cells to 0. You can do this in the theme by changing the padding of even/oddRowCell